# Is there a possible way to give Batch file options to choose from and then use the random command to make it choose the options?

Tags: batch-file, random

Is there a possible way to give Batch file options to choose from and then use the random command to make it choose the options?

The question might not make sense, but what I want is for a batch file to select a word or sentence randomly. So for example, if I'd give it the options to select and show the words No, Yes, and Maybe, then I'd like it to choose one of those options randomly. If I'm not making sense, then basically what I want is to know if there's a way to do something similar to the %random% command but with words on a Batch file.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have to map a number to a word or phrase. The divisor for the random has to be the number of possibilities you have in the map.

```
@echo off

SET /a v=%random% %% 3 + 1

SET map=1-Yes;2-No;3-Maybe
CALL SET v=%%map:*%v%-=%%
SET v=%v:;=&rem.%

ECHO.%v%
pause
```